# How to render current angular route/page into a dialog on click of button

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have requirement to render contents current page into non-modal dialog so that user can navigate into different page/route. Keep previous page/route in non modal Dialog.

Basically every page carries a control which on click popups the current page contents into a non-modal dialog. They may open as many dialog as they want

Please suggest how to achieve this. Appreciate any references to this API